# How to convert CSV columns to normalized np arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have data in the following format:

```
1495573445.162, 0, 0.021973, 0.012283, -0.995468, 1
1495573445.172, 0, 0.021072, 0.013779, -0.994308, 1
1495573445.182, 0, 0.020157, 0.015717, -0.995575, 1
1495573445.192, 0, 0.017883, 0.012756, -0.993927, 1
1495573445.202, 0, 0.021194, 0.012161, -0.994705, 1
```

without a header. There are around 1000 similar rows.

I want to normalize the third, fourth, and fifth columns into np arrays.

I have the following code.

```
import numpy as np

Acc1_x = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer1.csv', delimiter=',')
Acc1_y = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer1.csv', delimiter=',')
Acc1_z = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer1.csv', delimiter=',')

Acc2_x = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer2.csv', delimiter=',')
Acc2_y = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer2.csv', delimiter=',')
Acc2_z = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer2.csv', delimiter=',')

Acc3_x = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer3.csv', delimiter=',')
Acc3_y = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer3.csv', delimiter=',')
Acc3_z = np.genfromtxt('Accelerometer3.csv', delimiter=',')

Acc1_x_normed = (Acc1_x - Acc1_x.min()) / Acc1_x.ptp()
Acc1_y_normed = (Acc1_y - Acc1_y.min()) / Acc1_y.ptp()
Acc1_z_normed = (Acc1_z - Acc1_y.min()) / Acc1_y.ptp()

Acc2_x_normed = (Acc2_x - Acc2_x.min()) / Acc2_x.ptp()
Acc2_y_normed = (Acc2_y - Acc2_y.min()) / Acc2_y.ptp()
Acc2_z_normed = (Acc2_z - Acc2_z.min()) / Acc2_z.ptp()

Acc3_x_normed = (Acc3_x - Acc3_x.min()) / Acc3_x.ptp()
Acc3_y_normed = (Acc3_y - Acc3_y.min()) / Acc3_y.ptp()
Acc3_z_normed = (Acc3_z - Acc3_z.min()) / Acc3_z.ptp()

print Acc1_x_normed
print Acc1_y_normed
print Acc1_z_normed

print Acc2_x_normed
print Acc2_y_normed
print Acc2_z_normed

print Acc3_x_normed
print Acc3_y_normed
print Acc3_z_normed
```

However, it prints out:

```
[  1.00000000e+00   6.65681116e-10   6.79158889e-10   6.76190128e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33432096e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.64579197e-10   6.76536483e-10   6.73108367e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33321904e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.64579197e-10   6.78750350e-10   6.72710526e-10
  -5.20201801e-13   1.33321904e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.64916187e-10   6.79567423e-10   6.72057929e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33355603e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.65568779e-10   6.81056484e-10   6.73282209e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33420862e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.64252896e-10   6.78771073e-10   6.71313064e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33289274e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.61436566e-10   6.71241501e-10   6.69088480e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33007639e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.70966021e-10   6.84606942e-10   6.79750611e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33960584e-09]
[  1.00000000e+00   6.70894477e-10   6.84147587e-10   6.82066111e-10
   0.00000000e+00   1.33953430e-09]
```

I need it to print out the entire 1000 or so values in each of the columns from the csv file but it only prints out 6 in each array.

Comment: `Acc1_x` is no different from `Acc1_y` in your code, etc. That problem pervades the rest of your code; you need to reference particular columns somehow, either by index or by name. Maybe start with [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)?

Comment: Do you realize that `Acc1_x` (and the others) is a (n,6) 2d array?  Have you read enough `numpy` to know how to index and perform operations on row, columns and/or the whole array?

Comment: @roganjosh would I just index the genfromtext with the right column number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *very* *close* just need to add the logic ***axis=0*** so

```
Acc1_x_normed = (Acc1_x - Acc1_x.min()) / Acc1_x.ptp()
```

becomes

```
Acc1_x_normed = (Acc1_x - Acc1_x.min(axis=0)) / Acc1_x.ptp(axis=0)
```

Comment: It works, but I'm getting a lot of NaN's and warnings about bad divisions. I believe it's possible I'm dividing by zero in some cases. Also, @roganjosh is correct that all my Acc_x, Acc_y, and Acc_z are about the same. I'm not sure how to alleviate that.

Comment: After the include numpy but before the other code you can say, np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore') to clear the warning messages.

Comment: To convert your nan (not a number) to zero add the logic Acc1_x_normed = np.nan_to_num(Acc1_x_normed)